# Fix "OMP: Error #15: Initializing libomp.dylib, but found libiomp5.dylib already initialized." in NON conda env

Tags: python, pip

I know there is a ton of threads asking this question. However, they all deal with `conda` envs and state `conda` packages conflicting libomps and the solution would be to install the `no-mkl` meta package.

I do not use conda but a "normal" `venv` created by Python3.9 (either from python.org installer or from `brew`) and install packages via `pip`.

Why would this also happen without conda and is there a way to solve it?

It happens when using [faster-whisper](https://github.com/guillaumekln/faster-whisper) in a `x86_64` venv, but not an `arm64` venv.